# How to write xs, sm, md, lg for material ui grid item which contains xs={12} full width of the layout?

Tags: material-ui

My objective is to write the same full width in `xs, sm, md, lg` for the Card display. Can anyone help me in this query?

This is my code:

```js
import {
  Grid,
  Card,
  CardHeader,
  Avatar,
  IconButton,
  CardContent,
  Typography
} from "@material-ui/core";

import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import MoreVertIcon from "@material-ui/icons/MoreVert";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Grid container spacing={1}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Card>
            <CardHeader
              avatar={<Avatar aria-label="recipe">R</Avatar>}
              action={
                <IconButton aria-label="settings">
                  <MoreVertIcon />
                </IconButton>
              }
              title="Shrimp and Chorizo Paella"
              subheader="September 14, 2016"
            />
            <CardContent>
              <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
                This impressive paella is a perfect party dish and a fun meal to
                cook together with your guests. Add 1 cup of frozen peas along
                with the mussels, if you like.
              </Typography>
            </CardContent>
          </Card>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

[Here is the Code Sandbox sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-resonance-913y5)

Comment: That `Card` is a block element and is already occupying the full width. Do you have a sample illustration of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything since breakpoints are inclusive.  Writing `xs={12} sm={12} md={12} lg={12} xl={12}` is the same as writing `xs={12}`.

Comment: @MacD - Hi, i want only upto Tablet View, after that it should allow me horizontal scrolling

Comment: @95faf8e76605e973 - Hi, i want only upto Tablet View, after that it should allow me horizontal scrolling